# Postgresql 12.8 - Can not convert text to json

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion, postgresql-12

I have an text column which contains valid json object.

I need to elect only on property from this object.
My code is:

```
    select 
        jsonb_array_elements(td.metadata::jsonb)
    from temp_data td
```

And I'm getting next error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
>
> DETAIL:  Token "type" is invalid.
>
> CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: [{type...
>
> SQL state: 22P02

P.S. Same script works OK in PostgreSQL 12.11

Comment: Well, then `metadata` contains values which are invalid JSON. I will believe Postgres more than your claim that it contains valid data

Comment: This is  a good example, why you should choose a validating data type to begin with. If the column had been defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`) from the start, you wouldn't have the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid `json`:

```
select  '[{type: 1}]'::json;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: select  '[{type: 1}]'::json;
```

Valid `json` input would be:

```
select  '[{"type": 1}]'::json;
     json      
---------------
 [{"type": 1}]
```

What is valid is spelled out in documentation here [JSON input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-KEYS-ELEMENTS).